# Prototype: Covert this visibility checking script to prototype syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, visible

How do I convert this small script to Prototype:

Basically I need to check if an element is visible or not, I do with jquery this way: `$('id_element').is(':visible');` but I dont know how to do it similar with Prototype.

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display:none">A Div</div>
<script>
if(document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display == 'none') alert('visible');
else alert('hidden');
</script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be:

```
$('myElementID').visible();
```

Note that you do not use '#' to reference the element by id like you do in jQuery.